# SQLite Connection String for iPhone Application in C#

Tags: iphone, string, sqlite, connection

I am trying to learn iPhone App Development using MonoDevelop and C#. I have created a sqlite database file `userinfodb_v1.sqlite` and placed it in a subfolder called Data in my project. Now I am trying to write the connection for the application to fetch data from the tables. I haven't got much clue as to how I should form the connection string as I have only about started. This is what I am doing:

```
string strconn=Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Data");
scon=new SqliteConnection(strconn);
scon.Open();
```

However this is not working as the connection is failing. What should I do to establish a connection? Where is the error in my code? Can you help me correct it? Any help will be massively appreciated. What does `Environment.SpecialFolder` mean? Where should I keep the database file in order to access it properly?

Many Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

When your application starts you need to copy the database file from the bundle to the Personal folder.